# Is there a platform agnostic HTML5 map service?

Tags: html, dictionary, geolocation, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I have a Blazor combined client/server side app that uses HTML5 geolocation to return the user device latitude/longitude. I'd like to be able to provide the general "area" the user is in - a bit of a confirmation to the user the thing is working; and someday potentially enable the user to get lat/long for other locations as well. I have not been able to find a native HTML5 map service to go along with its geolocation capabilities, and in fact nearly every search leads to how to connect to Google Maps. I'm using Blazor, though, because I want the app to run and function on essentially every browser, so want to avoid Google Maps or Apple Maps, etc. I also checked quick on GitHub for potential API solutions but didn't see any. Ideas? Thanks!